# ListView goes upside when slide it to bottom in android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Hello I am newbie to android and working on a list-view demo,I recently found a weird behavior of list-view when i scroll it down it forcefully comes upside,Can anybody tell me what should be the reason behind this behavior.I am posting my code here.

**activity**

```
package one.tusk.stush.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.company.stush.R;

import java.util.List;

import one.tusk.stush.SearchPostActivity;
import one.tusk.stush.adapters.TimelineAdapter;
import one.tusk.stush.connect.Post;
import one.tusk.stush.loaders.SearchPostsLoader;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.ActionBarPullToRefresh;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener;

public class SearchPostsFragment extends BaseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Post>>, OnRefreshListener, OnScrollListener {

    public static android.widget.PopupMenu popupMenu;
    private int index = -1;
    private int top = 0;
    TimelineAdapter mTimelineAdapter;
    SearchPostsLoader mTimelineLoader;
    PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
    ListView mListViewTimeline;
    ProgressBar mProgressBarLoading;
    TextView mTextViewNoItems;
    ImageView im;
    Menu mm;
    int total;

    int lastPosition;
    int lastTop;
    String search;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        search = getArguments().getString("search");

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline_other, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    public void onResume () {

        super.onResume();
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        mListViewTimeline.setSelectionFromTop(
                lastPosition,
                lastTop
        );


//      if(index!=-1){
//          mListViewTimeline.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
//        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);



    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


        lastPosition = mListViewTimeline.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = mListViewTimeline.getChildAt(0);
        lastTop = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

//       lastPosition = mListViewTimeline.getSelectedItemPosition();
//       int lastPositionInGroup = lastPosition - mListViewTimeline.getFirstVisiblePosition();
//       lastTop = mListViewTimeline.getChildAt( lastPositionInGroup ).getTop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_post, menu);
        //MenuItem refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
        //refreshItem.setVisible(true);

        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_profile_menu, menu);
    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.search22) {
            //   Log.d("MyApp", "action bar clicked");


            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchPostActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("View_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        total = 0;
        mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).allChildrenArePullable().listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        mProgressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
        mTextViewNoItems = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewNoItems);

        mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());



        mListViewTimeline = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeline);
        mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);
        mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);

        mListViewTimeline.setOnScrollListener(this);

        //  mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        mListViewTimeline.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Post>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        mTimelineLoader = new SearchPostsLoader(getActivity(), mListViewTimeline, search);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        return mTimelineLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Post>> arg0, List<Post> data) {

        mTimelineAdapter.setData(data);
        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
        mTextViewNoItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mTextViewNoItems);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Post>> arg0) {

        mTimelineAdapter.setData(null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        mTextViewNoItems.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);


    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount && visibleItemCount != 0) {
            if (mTimelineLoader.loadMore() && !mTimelineLoader.loading()) {
                total = totalItemCount - 1;
                lastPosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v =  view.getChildAt(0);
                lastTop = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                mTimelineLoader.onContentChanged();

            }


        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    public void searchPost(String query)
    {



        search  = query;
        lastPosition = 0;
        lastTop = 0;
        mTimelineAdapter.clear();
        // mTimelineLoader.loadInBackground();
        Log.d("12","UPDATE");
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
  package one.tusk.stush.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.company.stush.R;

import java.util.List;

import one.tusk.stush.connect.Post;
import one.tusk.stush.views.PostListItem;

public class TimelineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public TimelineAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_item_post);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public void setData(List<Post> data) {
        setNotifyOnChange(true);
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Post post = getItem(position);
        PostListItem view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view =  (PostListItem) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);


        } else {
            view = (PostListItem) convertView;

        }
        view.setPost(post);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you scroll downside It's going reverse or Scrolling is slower than you expect ?

Comment: can you post Search Adapter code ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna -actually on scroll some more data appending to listView,but after update my listView comes to first position.

Comment: @GiapLee - yes brother.just wait 2 min.i am posting my adpater.

Comment: @GiapLee-please see my update frend

Comment: I think your problem at code line:  mListViewSearchUsers.setAdapter(searchAdapter);  i think asynctask called repeat by onQueryTextSubmit(...) while you are scolling listview

Comment: You can      use this                                                                                                           if (searchAdapter== null) {
            mListViewSearchUsers.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        } else {                                                                                                                            searchAdapter.setData(results);
            mListViewSearchUsers.notifyDatasetChange();
        }

Comment: @GiapLee-what changes needed in my code.

Comment: @vaibhavrockstar - What changes neeed in my code..?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid please,check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

**Change your code**

```
            if(results.size() > 0){
                SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this);
                searchAdapter.setData(results);
                mListViewSearchUsers.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                textNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                textNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textNotFound.setText("No users found");
            }
```

**to**

```
            if(results.size() > 0){
                SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this);
                   if (searchAdapter== null) { 
                        searchAdapter.setData(results);
                        mListViewSearchUsers.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                   } else { 
                 searchAdapter.setData(results); 
                 mListViewSearchUsers.notifyDatasetChange();
               }
                textNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                textNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textNotFound.setText("No users found");
            }
```

**Change some code in adapter (comment some code)**

```
 public void setData(List<User> data) {
   // clear();
    if (data != null) {
        addAll(data);
       // notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

**Update:(problem resolved by comm‌​ents this line)**

mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

I hope this will help you.

Comment: now wat happened is when i scroll down still it goes down...:(

Comment: because , you are using         mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);comments this line please. and re-check again

Comment: -ok brother.let me check.and pls help me.i need it badly